# Move Faders X32 Behringer Console

Tags: behringer, console

I have an X32 Behringer Console, that looks like [image: this] and the Channels 1-16 are: A1, A2, A3, A4, A5,A6, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, C1, C2, C3, C4. And A1-6 are unused, but I have channels in Ch17-32, and in Aux In/USB, Fx Returns, that I ***do*** want on the main page (So I don't have to keep switching back and forth to change the channel levels. I basically want everything on the main page, all organized and stuff. So I want to somehow move the Aux 1,2 into Ch1-2, but It does not seem to link. (When I move Aux1,2 on the Ch1-16 page, it also needs to be linked with the Aux1,2 on the Aux In/USB, Fx Returns page.

---

Answer (score 2):

The X32 does not support user-defined fader banks. You cannot change them.

The first page will always have Channels 1–16, the second page always Channels 17–32, the third page always the Aux Returns, USB player, and FX Returns, and the fourth page always the Bus Masters.

Answer (score 1):

in fact you can move around inputs
select the channel you want to change
goto Config and change the source

in your example
CH1 source = AUX1